# C++ error too big for character

Tags: c++, character, utf

Here is were i get the error.
To explain, i want to print the →  character which according to http://www.endmemo.com/unicode/unicodeconverter.php

The code is 2192. but i may be using the wrong code if so what is the right way to print → .

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    UINT oldcp = GetConsoleOutputCP();
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);

    cout<<"\x2192"<<endl;

    SetConsoleOutputCP(oldcp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not `2912` in UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

A char on your platform is 8 bits. Your code part `"\x2192"` tries to put 16 bits in it. What will not fit, so you get the warning.

You possibly meant several characters, like `"\x21\x92"` or `"\x92\x21"`? That creates a valid string with two chars (+ the 0). You may still adjust it to have the proper value if comments are correct.

Comment: \x21\x92 gives two different symbols, any suggestion on how i will make my char more than 8 bits or somthing else?

Comment: your fragment implies you aim for UTF-8. You should read up how to encode your code point in UTF-8 way.

Comment: i have read around and i am getting dead ends or too complicated ways. i will make another question, what would you say would be the easiest way to print out that symbol?

Answer (score 0):

From the use of `_tmain` and `SetConsoleOutputCP` I guess you are mostly about Windows.  I'm afraid I don't know much about that; hopefully someone who knows more about that specific case will chime in, but this program generates the output you're looking for in a quick test I tried here with a UTF-8 terminal.  Here's the program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "\xE2\x86\x92" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And example output:

```
$ make example && ./example
c++     example.cpp   -o example
→
```

I just directly output the UTF-8 encoding of the → character.

Equivalently (at least for clang):

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "→" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: std::cout << "\xE2\x86\x92" << std::endl; just gives 3 different symbols

Comment: Is that the program's fault?  Or the terminal you're running it in?

Comment: i really don't know... i am completely new to this thing

Comment: Sorry - I don't know anything about Windows.  I do know the code I have here works fine on Unicode-aware terminals on Mac OS X and a linux machine I tested on here.